# *.ics file to Google calendar in android

Tags: android

I have to read *.ics file from the download files by using my application and transfer the data in to Google calendar in android. I am new to android. I need some help to do this.Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An ics file conforms to the iCal format. A google search brings up this Java iCal parser.

http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page

See also this intro to the iCalendar format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar